# Inconsistent resolutions on devices with Software Controls

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, monogame

I am making a game with MonoGame.Android using Xamarin.

I have found that devices with Software controls (highlighted here in red) give inconsistent resolutions.

[image: Android Software Controls]

Specifically, the issue occurs for apps that are authored in Landscape Orientation but opened while the phone is in Portrait Orientation. *When you do this, the phone ignores the physical orientation of the phone and renders in Landscape mode regardless.*

For example, I have created an emulator for Samsung Galaxy S2. I cloned 2 copies, 1 with software controls (S2Soft), and the other with hardware controls (S2Hard). I started my app on both phones while in both portrait orientation and landscape.

In Game.Initialize I check the values for PreferredBackBufferWidth and PreferredBackBufferHeight. Here is what I found:

**S2Soft:**

- Portrait: 736x480
- Lanscape: 744x480

**S2Hard:**

- Portrait: Res: 800x480
- Landscape: Res: 800x480

Now, I understand that S2Soft may have a smaller resolution compared to S2Hard (in order to make room for the software buttons), I don't understand why S2Soft has two *different* resolutions depending on the orientation of the phone at startup.

Has anyone dealt with this before? This is an issue for me because my UI is placed based on those resolutions, and if someone starts the app in portrait mode, that are placed incorrectly. It also leaves thin boxes on the side of the screen when the backbuffer is not being rendered.

Here is an example of the thin bars (the blue bars at the top and bottom are not there if started in landscape mode).

[image]

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**

Adding the following to my Activity configuration fixed the issue.

```
ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Landscape
```

By adding this line, the activity switches to landscape orientation before the MonoGame is initialized, and avoids the issues completely.

```
    [Activity (Label = "Swipe Tap Smash", 
    MainLauncher = true,
    Icon = "@drawable/icon_large",
    Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash",
    AlwaysRetainTaskState = true,
    LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTask,
    ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Landscape,
    ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation |
    Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden |
    Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Keyboard)]
public class Activity1
```

**Long Answer**

I looked into this and found that what I am seeing is as designed in MonoGame. If you look at ResetClientBounds in MonoGame\v3.0\MonoGame.Framework\GraphicsDeviceManager.cs, you will find this comment:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This method is used by MonoGame Android to adjust the game's drawn to area to fill
    /// as much of the screen as possible whilst retaining the aspect ratio inferred from
    /// aspectRatio = (PreferredBackBufferWidth / PreferredBackBufferHeight)
    ///
    /// NOTE: this is a hack that should be removed if proper back buffer to screen scaling
    /// is implemented. To disable it's effect, in the game's constructor use:
    ///
    ///     graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
    ///     graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = Window.ClientBounds.Height;
    ///     graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = Window.ClientBounds.Width;
    ///
    /// </summary>
    internal void ResetClientBounds()
```

This is why we see the bars at the side of the screen; MonoGame has already created the render area, and has now been told to render to a different sized area. Rather than create a new render surface, or stretch the existing one, it letter boxes the image to fit as best it can.

However, this shouldn't actually be triggered in my case, as it should not be switching orientation after the fact. That is fixed my setting `ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Landscape` in my Activity.